# Spatial Queens Weights on Continental USA using Pysal

Tags: geospatial, geopandas, pysal

I´m new to spatial analysis and I want to get spatial weights (Queens) for all the counties in continental USA. As far as I know, I need to exclude all the small Islands, which are technically part of continental USA but not adjacent to the mainland.

I tried getting the weights of continental USA including all non adjascent Island (weights = ps.lib.weights.Queen.from_dataframe(df)), but I get an "object is not iterable" error. Whats the best way to do this with Pysal / GeoPandas?
Many Thanks!